# Generating random sets of holdings using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate multiple (say, 100 000) random sets of holdings for users who can hold multiple holdings. For any given user, these holdings have to sum to 1. In theory, generating these random holdings can be done fairly easily in numpy:

```
num_users = 100000
num_holdings = 8

random_holdings = np.random.rand(num_users, num_holdings)
random_holdings /= np.sum(random_holdings, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This gives us

```
random_holdings
array([[0.044, 0.169, 0.204, ..., 0.051, 0.116, 0.176],
       [0.132, 0.078, 0.23 , ..., 0.102, 0.028, 0.204],
       [0.036, 0.182, 0.165, ..., 0.138, 0.065, 0.04 ],
       ...,
       [0.195, 0.028, 0.136, ..., 0.147, 0.113, 0.22 ],
       [0.19 , 0.237, 0.061, ..., 0.23 , 0.109, 0.046],
       [0.181, 0.111, 0.1  , ..., 0.166, 0.126, 0.199]])
```

The problem with this is that it leads to many similar holdings sets and relatively few concentrated holdings sets. For example:

```
len(np.where(random_holdings > 0.5)[0])
```

gives a result of 24, ie there are only 24 holdings out of the entire 100 000 which are greater than 0.5.

Could anybody kindly recommend a better randomization method or just a more sensible overall approach, so that I have fewer similar sets of holdings and more concentrated sets of holdings?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the distribution of holdings to be if not uniform?

Comment: Seems more like a mathematical problem to me.

Comment: @Alex - yes - to be honest I'm not quite sure. np.random.rand produces a uniform distribution, but the end result of the process above isn't really uniform - it's over-concentrated in a 1/n set of holdings and under-concentrated in the extremes.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you ask for "a better randomization method", but "better" is not well-defined.  But if you want something to experiment with, try `random_holdings = np.random.pareto(1, size=(num_users, num_holdings))` (and then normalize like you already do).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - that seems to work a lot better, thank you. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for "a better randomization method", but "better" is not well-defined. If you just want *something* that will give more extreme variation in the holdings, you can try

```
random_holdings = np.random.pareto(1, size=(num_users, num_holdings))
```

and then normalize like you already do.

The first argument of [`pareto`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.pareto.html) controls the shape of the distribution. Use larger values for less extreme variation in the holdings.  You could also experiment with other heavy-tailed distributions.